# Firebase number of results that contain a value - iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I have a fairly simple scenario whereby I am trying to get the number of users with a particular favorite color. For example, I would like to retreive the number of users that have a favorite color of 'Blue'.

[image]

The following code will get me the number of children nodes each user has which in this case is 4 (favoriteColor, displayName, email and provider). I would instead like to get the number of users that have a particular favorite color.

```
let ref = Firebase(url: "https://project.firebaseio.com/users")
ref.queryOrderedByChild("favoriteColor").queryEqualToValue("Blue").observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in
            print(snapshot.childrenCount)

    })
```

I am trying to keep a live count of the number of users with a particular favorite color via UILabel so I will update the label each time there is a change to the number of results.

Is there currently a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by changing `.ChildAdded` to `.Value`.

I also changed `observeEventType` to `observeSingleEventOfType`

```
let ref = Firebase(url: "https://project.firebaseio.com/users")
    ref.queryOrderedByChild("favoriteColor").queryEqualToValue("Blue").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
    print(snapshot.childrenCount)

})
```

Hope this helps someone in future!